# How Can Newcomer Learn by Ear

Tags: ear-training, indian-classical, bansuri

I'm new to Bansuri and am practicing simple, repetitive tunes, such as [Om Jai Jagdish Hare](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nsPuUXwBI8)

A good friend requested I learn below song.

I am unable to find tutorials, or even notation anywhere.

This is such a lovely song, please tell best way to ear train

Comment: If you still need to work the repetitive tunes like "Jai jagadeesh hare" this is likely hard. Why not work at something intermediate like https://youtu.be/m7pQ4bvn68E ?  (Yeah I know it's devotional and not Bollywood)

Comment: Thank you @Rusi ... I like both devotional and Bollywood :-)

Comment: The repetitive part (words) is only slightly harder than Jai jagadeesh hare. The improvisatory parts (aaaas) you can ignore to start with. Add them as it comes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Please tell best way to ear train"

Well, there is no best way to train your ears. There will be always different methods that work better for different people...

However, here are some tips:

- Get to know all the intervals.

There are a lot of ear training apps you can train your ears with. There you get the first impressions of perfect, major, minor intervals...

If you can figure out the intervals, you'll be able to play any song by ear in any key.

This is because the interval relationship is the same in every major key for example. So if you haven't perfect pitch, you won't be able to tell the exact note name or pitch of a note you've heard, but what you can train is relative pitch.

If you know "the second note is a major third below the first one, then the next one is a perfect fifth up..." it doesn't matter on which note you start the song, because no matter where you'll start, you'll always play the correct tune just in a different key.

- After you got your intervals, start simple!

Don't try to transcribe any pop songs with 20 instruments. Just take a slow piano piece and try to recreate it by ear. In my opinion the piano is an easy instrument to figure out by ear. When you get better and better, you go to other instruments and songs with more instruments.

Don't try to figure out all the instruments at once. Play it once and try to figure out the vocal melody line, then run the whole thing again and just focus on the bass line etc.

That's how I've learned it and I got better and better over time, but it's still hard for me to transcribe orchestral scores by ear for exammle, because there are so many instruments blending into each other and sometimes it can be quite hard...

- Don't think this is a one day process.

You won't get better unless you train it over and over again - It's going to take a lot of time until you will get good at it.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what Andy said, since your question is specifically about Indian music, I feel I need to add that you will be very confused if you try to figure out all the ornamentation right at the beginning. The trick is to be able to get a plain melody line without the ornamentation first, and layer the ornamentation onto the basic melody line eventually.

It really is a question of practice. It gets easier with time.

Answer (score 1):

To learn to play any song on flute, easiest way to get started is look for keyboard/harmonium tutorials online which are relatively easy to find and play the same notes on flute. You can improvise those notations by adding flute specific sounds like gamak and meend wherever it is necessary. Another important part is to listen to the song again and again so you know where to use meends and gamaks exactly.

The easiest way I found for ear practice was by playing patterns repeatedly on flute like sa re ma ga, re ga pa ma etc. I then remember phrases and can recognise the phrases in the song and hence the rest of the relative notes.

Comment: You mean alankars? I started doing that, then I decided to go straight for simple tunes. Perhaps I shall revisit alankars.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Also, learning alankars in different ragas is usually much more helpful since they are used in many songs instead of just shuddha swaras. For example, learning alankars and mrukhis in raga yaman will help you identify songs such as moh moh ke dhaage, laal ishq, breathless, ek dil ek jaan and many such famous songs since they follow typical raga yaman chalan. "pa re sa" "ni re ga ma" "dha sa ni re sa ni" "ma dha pa" etc etc.